# Extending a Class by Adding a Button

Tags: java, button, graphics, awt, extend

This is probably an elementary question. However, I have completed reading the 12th Chapter of Java Programming for the Absolute Beginner and have approached the Challenges section. I cannot quite get the progam to display a labeled button with the extended class.

The specification states:

> Extend the JPRButton3D class to create a button that displays a label just like
>   the AWT Button class you're so familiar with by now.  As an extra test, override
>   the isFocusable() method so that your button class can be traversed and make sure you 
>   paint some special graphic to make it obvious when your button has focus.

How can I edit my code of LabelButton3D and LabelButton3DTest to accomplish this task?

An answer to this specification can potentially aid many new Java programmers in extending their own classes.

Thank you very much for your time and cooperation reagrding this matter.

HERE IS THE CODE FOR JPRButton3D:

```
package jpr.lightweight;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/**
 * A lightweight 3D Button class that fires actions when clicked.
 * When it is enabled it appears {@link #RAISED RAISED}, when
 * it is pressed it appears {@link #SUNK SUNK}, and when it is
 * not enabled, it appears {@link #FLAT FLAT}.
 */
public class JPRButton3D extends JPRRectComponent3D {
  private boolean pressed;
  /**
   * This <code>JPRButton3D</code>'s <code>ActionListener</code>.
   */
  protected ActionListener actionListener;
  private String actionCommand;

  /**
   * Constructs a new <code>JPRButton3D</code> with minimum size
   */
  public JPRButton3D() {
    this(ABSOLUTE_MIN_WIDTH, ABSOLUTE_MIN_HEIGHT, 1);
  }

  /**
   * Constructs a new <code>JPRButton3D</code> with the given dimensions.
   * @param wide the width
   * @param high the height
   */
  public JPRButton3D(int wide, int high) {
    this(wide, high, 1);
  }

/**
 * Constructs a new <code>JPRButton3D</code> with the given dimensions
 * and border magnitude.
 * @param wide the width
 * @param high the height
 * @param border_magnitude the border's magnitude
 */

public JPRButton3D(int wide, int high, int border_magnitude) {
  super(wide, high, RAISED, border_magnitude);
  enableEvents(AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
}

public void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
  if (isEnabled() & e.getModifiers() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) {
    switch(e.getID()) {
      case MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED:
        pressed = true;
        current_appearance = SUNK;
        repaint();
        break;
      case MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED:
        if (pressed) {
          pressed = false;
          current_appearance = RAISED;
          repaint();
       }
       break;
      case MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED:
        if (pressed) {
          current_appearance = RAISED;
          repaint();
          if (actionListener != null) {
            actionListener.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this,
              ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, actionCommand,
              e.getModifiers()));
          }
        }
        break;
     }
   }
   super.processMouseEvent(e);
}

/**
 * Adds the specified <code>ActionListener</code>
 * @param listener <code>ActionListener</code> to add
 */
 public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
   actionListener = AWTEventMulticaster.add(actionListener, listener);
 }

/**
 * Removes the specified <code>ActionListener</code>
 * @param listener <code>ActionListener</code> to remove
 */
public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
  actionListener = AWTEventMulticaster.remove(actionListener,
                                                 listener);
}

/**
 * Sets the action command associated with action events.
 * @param command The action command.
 */
public void setActionCommand(String command) {
  actionCommand = command;
}
 /**
  * Gets the action command associated with action events.
  * @return the action command
  */
public String getActionCommand() {
  return actionCommand;
}
/**
 * Enables or disables this <code>JPRButton3D</code>.
 * @param b <code>true</code> to enable, <code>false</code> to disable
 */
public void setEnabled(boolean b) {
  if (b) current_appearance = RAISED;
  else current_appearance = FLAT;
  repaint();
  super.setEnabled(b);
}
```

}

HERE IS MY CODE FOR LabelButton3DTest (to extend JPRButton3D):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import jpr.lightweight.JPRButton3D;

public class LabelButton3DTest extends GUIFrame {

LabelButton3D[] b;
String s;


public LabelButton3DTest() {
    super("LabelButton3D Test");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
   b = new LabelButton3D[1];

   b[0] = new LabelButton3D("Favorite Button"); 
   b[0] = new LabelButton3D(75, 35, 1);
   add(b[0]);


   pack();
   setVisible(true);
}

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       new LabelButton3DTest();


   }

}
```

HERE IS MY CODE FOR LabelButton3D:

```
public class LabelButton3D extends JPRButton3D {

public LabelButton3D(String label) {

}
 public LabelButton3D(int wide, int high, int border_magnitude) {
 super(wide, high, border_magnitude); 
}




}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels not a problem, will do...

Comment: all those methods are implemented in Swing JButtons, methods for Mouse Events are accesible from ButtonModel, is there real reason to do 10steps back by using prehistoric AWT Componens,

Comment: mKorbel is right, skip the AWT stuff. also your actionlisteners are messed up, they should be anonymous inner classes but you have the syntax all wrong.

Comment: You should use a `JButton`. What's the point in using extremely outdated and difficult to use AWT?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do too much all at once. I suggest that you start by finding one part of the problem which you can compile and run. Even the most veteran programmers wouldn't try to write a complete program all at once before trying to compile and run it. We usually write a few lines of code, compile and run it, then write a few more lines of code.